# Can I use Blockchain records to verify a purchase

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I am new in the Bitcoin field, but I wondered, if I paid bitcoins to a store to buy something from the internet, then if the store did not send what I purchased, is there a way I could use the blockchain to verify the transaction, say to sue the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction itself would be publicly visible, but you'd have to first prove that the address you sent the coins to is owned by the company, and that you were the one sending them, and also what the payment was for. If you had some proof that the transaction was for the item you bought, then yes, it would be easily verifiable that the transaction was legit. But bitcoin addresses are just random looking numbers and letters, so the company could claim that they didn't own the address you sent the payment to (and so they never received the money) or that the payment was for something else you purchased off them, not the item in question.

Comment: Are not there any ways to overcome this shortage?

Comment: What shortage? I don't understand your question

Comment: Sorry if  my question was not clear, you wrote "... so the company could claim that they didn't own the adress you sent the adress to .... or that the payment was for something else ..." So is there a way to fix that (to legally force the company to pay back the money or to give us the item we asked for?